# TeamCity: TFS Connection stops working after upgrade to 10.0 (from 9.1.7)

Tags: teamcity

I upgraded TeamCity from 9.1.7 to 10.0 and as soon as I did all TFS VCS Roots stopped working with an error saying...

`Unable to connect to TFS server: The SOAP endpoint http://tfs.corp.mydomain.com:8080/tfs/Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx could not be contacted. HTTP status: 503`

I tried changing TFS URL to an incorrect URL to see if error message changed and no, same message which tells me something is up .

I have proxy settings in TeamCity set via JVM Parameters and have confirmed that nonProxyHost wildcard is working (my corporate GITHUB connection is connecting)...

```
-Dproxyset=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxyserver.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=3218 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="*.mydomain.com" -Dhttps.proxyHost=myproxyserver.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=3218 -Dhttps.nonProxyHosts="*.mydomain.com";
```

My TFS URL (http://tfs.corp.mydomain.com:8080/tfs) is a sub domain of nonProxyHosts wildcard above.

Everything was working before I upgraded.

I know there was a number of TFS feature improvements in 10.0 (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/79726430).

Does anyone know if there is any other configuration I need to do to get it working again?

**UPDATE:**

- Using TFS 2015
- Can access TFS url from browser on build server
- Can access TFS server from Visual Studio Team Explorer installed on build server

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? Can you navigate to the TFS web UI in a web browser from the TeamCity server?

Comment: TFS 2015. Yes can get to same URL from browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to YouTrack issue with details and fix: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-46484

**Summary...**

Resolved issue with a new tfs plugin build (http://ftp.intellij.net/pub/.teamcity/TW-46484/tfs-plugin-42052.zip) where fixed issues with http.nonProxyHosts in tfs java working mode and locating Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.Integration.dll assembly

**Problem was...**

According to my logs tfs plugin selects java working mode to connect to tfs server, where http.nonProxyHosts and https.nonProxyHosts options unsupported *AND*  tfs plugin unable to locate Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.Integration.dll assemble in Visual Studio 2015 installation

**Steps to resolve...**

1. Shutdown the TeamCity server.
2. Copy the zip archive into the {TeamCity Data Directory}/plugins directory
3. Start the TeamCity server
4. I could then go to VCS Root and Test Connection to see 'Connection Successful!'